# Django: Update child select box choices depending on parent select box choice

Tags: python, django, select, admin, box

Does anybody know how to automatically update the options of a "child" select box depending on the choice of the "parent" select box in the admin page?

**The problem:** I have two select boxes. In the first one I choose e.g. a car brand. Once I choose the car brand I want the "child" select box options to update with the models of that brand.

I am using ForeignKey properly in my models and all the models are correct but if you can give me some guidance to solve this issue I would be grateful. Thanks!

**Solved:** I've used smart_selects. https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Comment: I have tried to clarify your question and improve the example. Please confirm that it is correct. I am also interested in this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Thank you. Hope I will get an answer now..

Comment: I have solved my problem. I used Django smart_selects. https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I used Django smart_selects. github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript and Elementmanipulation:

save the car-models to JavaScript Vars: ie

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var porsche = {{ porsche|safe }};
var vw = {{ vw|safe }};
</script>
```

And in you JavaScript you can specify a new Change Method for your Parent select box:

```
$('#parent_select').change(function(){
    changeCars();
});
```

The function could then manipulate the child select box:

```
var newCarList = [];
val =$('#parent_select').val();
if (val=='porsche'){
    newCarList = porsche;
}
else if (val == 'vw'){
    newCarList = vw;
}
else{
    //some Error handling
}

select = document.getElementById('child_select');
while (select.firstChild) {
select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
// to remove all previously added childs (option fields)
}

for (var i = 0; i < newCarList.length; i ++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = newCarList[i];
    opt.innerHTML = newCarList[i];
    select.appendChild(opt);
    //append all new Childs to the child_select
}
```

This possibility will work but is quite slow since Object manipulation is not the fastest way.
Another possibility would be to create different child selects and use show/hide to only display the correct one according to the value of the parent_select.